# How to solve Tesseract "Failed loading language 'eng'" problem in a Docker image

Tags: python, docker, runtime-error, tesseract

I recently received an error such as:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 287, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 263, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, "read_params_file: Can't open ][|~_}{=!#%&«§><:;—?¢°*@, Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.")
```

I have a python file where I specify the pytesseract location:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"to/my/path"

then I also included the tesseract and pytessearch in requirements and install tesseract-ocr in dockerfile.

I do not understand why it happens but can anyone assist?

I actually also copied my tesseract-ocr folder to image in dockerfile

```
COPY tesseract-ocr .
```

Edited:

Below is my requirements:

```
opencv-python==4.5.1.48
openpyxl==3.0.6
packaging==20.8
pandas==1.2.1
pathlib==1.0.1
patsy==0.5.1
pdfminer.six==20200517
pdfplumber==0.5.25
Pillow==8.1.0
prov==2.0.0
pycryptodome==3.9.9
pydot==1.4.1
PyMuPDF==1.16.14
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pytesseract==0.3.7
tesseract
```

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.7-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ARG src_folder= "folder/"
ARG src_ocr= "Tesseract-OCR/"
COPY ${src_folder} .
COPY ${src_ocr} .
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install all the required dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
        yasm \
        pkg-config \
        libswscale-dev \
        libtbb2 \
        libtbb-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libtiff-dev \
        libavformat-dev \
        libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get --fix-missing update && apt-get --fix-broken install && apt-get install -y poppler-utils && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr && \
    apt-get install -y libtesseract-dev && apt-get install -y libleptonica-dev && ldconfig && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 && apt install -y python-opencv
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./folder/main.py" ]
```

Comment: Is this question not valid? Can anyone assist? I cant seem to find any solution for days.

Comment: Can anyone help me in this please? Been stucked with these for a week now and still could not find a way to solve it

Comment: Still cant find any way to do it.

Comment: Can you please add your `requirements.txt` file to your question? - It would be good if you could include a minimally complete version of your `main.py` that exhibits the problem. It's hard to know if anything else is needed.  Try to reduce the problem down to something that you're sure others can reproduce just from what you supply in your question.  In other words, try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I included my requirements. thank you.

Comment: I also included the part which caused the issue, if you dont mind could you please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here...

The primary problem is a strange one.  The `apt-get` package `tesseract-ocr-eng` is installed as a transient dependency of one of the other packages you install with `apt-get`:

```
# apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng
...
tesseract-ocr-eng is already the newest version (1:4.00~git30-7274cfa-1).
```

and that package installs an English trained data file in the right place:

```
# ls -l /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4113088 Sep 15  2017 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

and yet you get this error message suggesting that Tesseract can't find this file.

I did some Googling, and after trying a number of different things that allowed Tesseract to work, I came to this most concise solution to your problem.  Just add this line near the end of your `Dockerfile`, like just before the last `CMD` line that sets the Docker command to be executed:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata -O /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata 2> /dev/null
```

This command replaces the previously installed `eng.traineddata` file with another one that I found on the internet.  It is much larger than the previously installed file:

```
# ls -l /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23466654 Feb 14 20:17 /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

By replacing the previously installed `eng.traineddata` file with this new version, your code starts to run fine.  I didn't have your image data, obviously, so I had to change your code a bit to use my own image for testing.  When I supplied an image with some text in it, I got back the text as the result of calling `pytesseract.image_to_string`.  So this one fix should be all you need.

There is a second problem here.  Your `pytesseract.image_to_string` call is being garbled somehow by the fact that you're breaking it across multiple lines. To fix just this one issue, you can edit the call so that the string constant is all on one line:

```
infor = pytesseract.image_to_string(im,
                                     lang="eng",
                                     config='--dpi 300 --psm 6 --oem 2 -c tessedit_char_blacklist=][|~_}{=!#%&«§><:;—?¢°*@,')
```

When I made just this change, the part of the error message you're getting about **"Can't open ..."** goes away.  If you fix just that, you're left with the error message:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, "Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.")
```

It's interesting that if you apply just the first fix, both problems go away, as you don't get an error message at all.  I don't know what's up with that.

I believe that I've given you all that you need to know.  If you have additional problems, let us know.  If you want me to share my versions of your `Dockerfile` and `main.py` files, I can do that.

Happy Tesseracting!

PS: I would recommend that you move the installation calls in your `Dockerfile`, the calls to `apt-get` and `pip`, to the top of the file.  This way, you can modify the parts of your `Dockerfile` specific to your application later on in the file, and your image build will happen quickly  rather than all of the long installation steps having to be done again.  This is an important practice to understand when building Docker images.  It will save you a ton of time watching long Docker image builds over and over again.  I did this right away when working on your problem, and I could rebuild and run the next version of the Docker image in just a few seconds rather than it taking more than a minute to rebuild and run each new image.

Comment: You were a big HELP!! I spent entire few days to figure this out but didnt get to solve it. I really appreciate it. Is it possible to remove the first part in your answer since it wont provide any info to the future readers since its my mistake at that part. its better to give a direct solution for future readers' reference.

Comment: That's a good point.  I do think it makes sense to address both issues, since both are represented in your error message.  I could move things around, however, so that the more minor problem is addressed later in the answer.  Alternatively, you could edit your question to not include that part of the problem, and I could then amend my answer to only address the one remaining problem...the important one.

Comment: I edited my answer to put the more important part of it at the beginning. I think it's fine the way it is now, although given the obscurity of the second issue, I'd have no problem with you removing that aspect from your question and from my answer as well.  If you choose to do so, feel free to edit to my answer yourself to match, if you so desire.

Comment: FYI, looks like master was renamed main in the tesseract repo so the command should be `wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/eng.traineddata -O /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/eng.traineddata`